# Reset rownames to particular format - make code more efficient

Tags: r, algorithm, performance, loops, optimization

I have a dataframe containing tokenized tweets. Baically, there are two columns, one with the id of the document (tweet) and one containing the words. I want to remove all words appearing less than two times in the whole dataset, and I have done that with a pretty ugly loop. Also, I needed to reset rownames: each rowname has to be in the format id.x where id is the document id and x the position of the word, so basically x has to increment until the following tweet, where it restarts. The first word of each sentence has rowname=id. Maybe it will be more clear looking at the code:

This is the structure of the df:

```
> token
        id           word
1        1          month
1.1      1           open
1.2      1       #postdoc
1.4      1         chemic
1.5      1      character
2        2       hardwork
2.1      2        biofuel
2.3      2           iowa
2.4      2          state
2.5      2           work
2.6      2           bill
2.7      2         revers
4        4          today
```

Notice ID's do not follow a specific pattern. Some of them (most actually) are missing.
This is how I remove all words appearing less than two times:

```
words<-unique(token$word)
for (i in words)
{
  if(length(which(token$word==i))<2)
  {
    token<-token[-which(token$word==i),]
  }
}
```

And this is how I reset the rownames:

```
x=y=1
for (i in 1:length(rownames(token)))
{
  print(i)
  if(token$id[i]!=x)
  {
    x=token$id[i]
    y=0
  }
  if(y>0)
  {
    rownames(token)[i]<-paste(x,".",y)
    y=y+1
  }
  else
  {
    rownames(token)[i]<-x
    y=y+1
  }
}
```

This code does exactly what it should, the problem is it take some hours to run (espetially the second loop) since it has to loop basically 400000 times.
If you have any idea, i'll be very interested and grateful to look at it!

UPDATE:
As asked from @lumartor, I show you the desired output on this example:

```
data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1,4, 4, 4, 4,4), word = c("month","open","#postdoc","chemic","today","month","lucas","open","#postdoc"), row.names = c(1, 1.1,1.2,1.4,4,4.1,4.2,4.3,4.4))
```

Becomes:

```
data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,4,4,4), word=c("month", "open", "#postdoc", "month", "open", "#postdoc"), row.names = c(1,1.1,1.2,4,4.1,4.2))
```

Comment: Do you really need the rownames or this info can be in another column?

Comment: if I change the word "hardwork" in row named "2" by "month" appling your code the rownames are  "1.1 and 2". Is this correct or the rownames may be "1 and 2" or "1.1 and 2.1"?

Comment: @lumartor I just could make that new column the new rownames afterwards, so it would not be a problem. Changing the word "hardwork" (as well as every other word) should have no impact (except if the word appears in less than two documents): the rowname as well as the ID should remain the same. However, i'll check my code again and let you know. Thanks for you intrest!

Comment: Please, put your desired output with the data: 

token <- data.frame(word = c("month","open","#postdoc","chemic","today","month","lucas","open","#postdoc"),
                      id = c(1, 1, 1, 1,4, 4, 4, 4,4))
  ;    rownames(token) <- c(1, 1.1,1.2,1.4,4,4.1,4.2,4.3,4.4)

Comment: @lumartor check the update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep the words that occur more than once and for each `id` create a row name.

```
library(dplyr)

token %>%
  add_count(word) %>%
  filter(n > 1) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(n = paste(id, row_number() - 1, sep = '.'), 
         n = sub('\\.0$', '', n)) %>%
  column_to_rownames('n') -> result
  
  
result

#    id     word
#1    1    month
#1.1  1     open
#1.2  1 #postdoc
#4    4    month
#4.1  4     open
#4.2  4 #postdoc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this attempt with the use of the tidyverse libraries:

```
library(tidyverse)
token %>%
  group_by(word) %>%
  mutate(n = n()) %>%
  filter(n > 1) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(m = c(0:(n()-1)),rowname = paste0(id, ".", m)) %>% 
  dplyr::select(rowname, id, word) %>%
  mutate(rowname = str_replace(rowname, "\\.0", ""))
```

Using data.table library:

```
  library(data.table)
  token <- as.data.table(token)
  result <- token[word %chin% token[duplicated(token, by="word")]$word
  ][, rowname:=paste0(id,".", 0:(.N-1)), by="id"
  ][, rowname := str_replace(rowname, "\\.0", "")]
```

Basen on Ronak Shah answer I have modified the tidyverse solution:

```
tidy <- function(token){
result <- token %>%
  add_count(word) %>%
  filter(n > 1) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(rowname = paste0(id, ".", c(0:(n()-1)))) %>% 
  mutate(rowname = str_replace(rowname, "\\.0", ""))
}

DT <- function(token){
  token <- as.data.table(token)
  result <- token[word %chin% token[duplicated(token, by="word")]$word
  ][, rowname:=paste0(id,".", 0:(.N-1)), by="id"
  ][, rowname := str_replace(rowname, "\\.0", "")]  
}

token <- data.frame(word = c("month","open","#postdoc","chemic","character","hardwork","biofuel","iowa","state","work","bill","revers","today","month","lucas","open","#postdoc"),
                    id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4,4))

# create a token2 with 1700000 rows
token2 <- data.frame(id=rep(token$id, 1e5), word=rep(token$word, 1e5))
```

The results for microbenhmark are:

```
> microbenchmark(tidy(token2), DT(token2), times=5)
Unit: seconds
         expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 tidy(token2) 4.752063 4.793552 4.913024 4.900735 4.965614 5.153155     5
   DT(token2) 4.165218 4.275900 4.275425 4.282281 4.321203 4.332524     5
```